# Quartz job not fired at all

Tags: c#, api, quartz-scheduler

I have a strange situation with my quartz job. It's not fired at all.
This is the configuration in global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new PnAwebAppControllerFactory());
        BootStrapper.ConfigureDependencies();
        GlobalConfig.CustomizeConfig(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        ConfigureQuartzJobs();
    }
```

It's at the end of my config and the method is the following

```
public static void ConfigureQuartzJobs()
    {
        // construct a scheduler factory
        var schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        // get a scheduler
        var sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        // Create job for emails in que for all companies
        var jobEmailsQued = JobBuilder.Create<EmailQueJob>().WithIdentity("EmailQueJob", "group1").Build();

        // Create trigger for jobEmailsQued
        var triggerJobEmailsQued =
            TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("TriggerEmailQueJob", "group1")
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0 0/2 * * * ?"))
                .ForJob(jobEmailsQued)
                .Build();

        // Schedule jobEmailsQued
        sched.ScheduleJob(jobEmailsQued, triggerJobEmailsQued);
    }
```

I'm using the API template app from visual studio. I'm doing something wrong?

Tnx!

After some testing i get the in the output screen

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Quartz.dll
```

For me it's strange because i have the job execution like this

```
public class EmailQueJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IMailMessageService _mailMessageService;

    private readonly AppLog _appLog;

    public EmailQueJob(IMailMessageService mailMessageService, AppLog appLog)
    {
        _mailMessageService = mailMessageService;
        _appLog = appLog;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some name");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
//                _appLog.LogError(ex, string.Format("Quartz job: email que, FAILED to execute.<br/>Error message: {0}.", ex.Message));
            var je = new JobExecutionException(ex);
            je.RefireImmediately = true;  //do something with the exception
            _appLog.LogError(ex, string.Format("Quartz job: email que, FAILED to execute.<br/>Error message: {0}.", je));
            throw je;  //throw JobExecutionException

        }

    }
}
```

For test at this moment it's only with a console message. The actual code for sending email i've tested it and works.

Comment: It appears that if i create a new project(mvc 4 api) with the code above it works fine. In this case i will have to see what it's not accepting Quartz commands. If i find a solution i will post it here.